# How can i add background image to both blog and sidebar with page builder in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog in wordpress and i want to add a background image to the blog post and sidebar aswell. I have attached the image

[image]

I am working on page builder .Can i get the result that i expected
 this is my admin panel
[image]

Comment: by using custom css you can set the middle section background img. please share your link.

Comment: http://allamericanlimo.com/blog/        this i my link

Comment: Assign background for this class(with-sidebar-wrapper) using css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below css in your theme custom css

```
.with-sidebar-container{ background-color:#6CF;}
```

Comment: thanks it helped me and i have appended  background image using css.  and it is with-sidebar-wrapper

Comment: Welcome! Happy to Help :)